# PowerShell - Replace out-file from / to _

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use PowerShell to export all jobs from several instances to .txt files.

But when I get to jobs which use “ / “ on their names, the files cannot be created due to OS naming restrictions.

Hence, I would like to export the jobs and replace the “ / “ from their names to “ _ ”.
Here is the query I am using.

```
$Loop = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance Source -Database DB -Query "SELECT DISTINCT [alias/host] as [SrcServer] FROM [DB].[dbo].[AllDatabases];" 

foreach ($JobsExport in $Loop) {
    foreach ($i in $JobsExport.SrcServer)   {
        $SrvFolderName = ($JobsExport.SrcServer) -replace '\\','_'

        $dir = "C:\Temp\All_Jobs\"+ $SrvFolderName

        #Create the folders
        if(!(Test-Path -Path $dir )){
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $dir
            Write-Host "Folder Created"
        }
        else
        {
          Write-Host "Folder already exists - skipping"
        }

        $srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" ($JobsExport.SrcServer);
        $srv.JobServer.jobs|foreach-Object {$_.script() > "C:\Temp\All_Jobs\$SrvFolderName\$SrvFolderName-$_.txt" | % ($SrvFolderName-$_.txt) -replace '\\','_' -Verbose      }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am slightly confused, but it could be just me. You have a loop where the iterator is `$i`. I don't see that used anywhere. You are replacing \ in your script rather than `/`. Just use the same syntax for `/`.

Comment: It also contains `($JobsExport.SrcServer)` when it should probably be `$_.SrcServer` while it's in the loop. It's a bit odd. The problem is likely that it's using `$_` in the filename instead of `$srvFolderName`.

Comment: I would like to know how to replace the "/" from the output file name. I noticed I created two loops and I removed one; The whole script runs as I expect, I need to know how to replace the "/" from the outfile, please;

Comment: You say you need to replace "/" but I only see your replacing "\\".

Comment: Whatever variable your output filename is in, you can just to `$variable.replace('/','_')`

Comment: I was able to make it work, by changing it to:  

`$srv.JobServer.jobs|foreach-Object {`
        
        `$FileName = ($_.Name) -replace '/','_' `

        ` $FilePath =`   `"E:\DBRefreshmentScripts\All_Jobs\$SrvFolderName\$FileName.txt" `
        
       ` $_.script() > $FilePath}`